# Is it possible to record voice with Bluetooth Mic and play it on device speaker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have achieved the above thing by overriding output port on Audio session as below,

```
    NSError *error;
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                                                           error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: AudioSession cannot use speakers");
    }
```

And this is working well with Wired Earphone Mic. Any help appreciated!